# How to pass a function as an argument to another function in Perl and then call it?

Tags: perl

I am new in Perl. I just need to send a general function that takes two parameters to another function and then call the first function from inside the second function. I am not very sure how that can be done. Here is the code I am trying to write.

```
sub add { return $_[0] + $_[1]; }
sub subt { return $_[0] - $_[1]; }

sub dosth
{
    my ($func, $num0, $num1) = @_;
    # how to call code $func with arguments $num0 and $num1 and return the return value of $func
}

print dosth(add, 3, 2) . " " . dosth(subt, 3, 2); # desired output: 5 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
sub add { return $_[0] + $_[1]; }
sub subt { return $_[0] - $_[1]; }

sub dosth {
    my ($func, $num0, $num1) = @_;
    return $func->($num0, $num1);
}

print dosth(\&add, 3, 2) . " " . dosth(\&subt, 3, 2); # 5 1
```

Online at http://codepad.org/RX1auCRn

The trick is to pass *references* to the subroutine to `dosth`, then you can call indirectly with the arrow.